# change text mode programmatically in windows mobile 6.5

Tags: windows, windows-mobile

In my mobile application i am setting password char of textbox programmatically.Is there any way that i can reset the textbox text mode to normal text from password.

I am doing this as i could not find watermark or hint feature for textboxes in windows mobile.

Please forward your valuable suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
myTextBox.PasswordChar = (char)0;
```

Comment: Thanks ctacke.It works fine.Normally if i am satisfied i do accept it,anyhow will work on that again.:)